# Connection of external points to polygons

Tags: qgis

I have a layer with houses of a city as polygons and address points with demographic data as a point layer. The points are laying outside of the houses.

How can I connect the data of the points to respectively the nearest house? Each house can include different address points, but I want each point just connected to one house.

I just know the 'Join attributes by nearest' with connecting just one point, but then I don't have control which point is already connected and which one isn't. In addition one point will be connected to two houses, if it's the nearest point to both.

Comment: If you use 'Join attributes by nearest' with the points layer first, then you will get each point connected to one house. Some houses may have no points connected, but this seems to be the outcome of the restrictions you've set.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to then sort the information by house? In the end, I only need a list with the data of the connected points once for each house. So for each house, e.g. the total number of residents of all connected points. It would be best storaged on a polygon layer so I can add back the houses without any information.

Comment: Probably, but hard to say without seeing a sample of your data.